# Récompensé par/de ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

There's a sentence in Claude Lévi-Strauss's *Tristes Tropiques* that has me a bit grammatically confused:

> Quand on avait mérité l'attention du maître, on était récompensé par la confiance qu'il vous faisait d'un malade pour un entretien particulier.

I'm unsure how the *par* and *de* are working here. Is it "récompensé d'un malade (par la confiance qu'il vous faisait)..."? Or "récompensé par la confiance (qu'il vous faisait) d'un malade..."? (I didn't think that "la confiance de qqch" could mean "being entrusted with something", but maybe I'm wrong?)

I think my confusion stems (at least in part) from not knowing whether *récompenser* usually goes with *par* or *de* (récompensé par qqch ou récompensé de qqch).

Comment: Let's say the **on** is we, here.  ***we were rewarded by his entrusting us with a patient for a private interview***. So confiance is by his entrusting us with and not that he trusted us. That's what's tricky here. Confiance is not trust, it's entrusting us with. Oh boy....

Comment: Confiance as in confier, remettre quelqu'un aux mains de quelqu'un d'autre. faire confiance n'est pas j'ai confiance ne vous. C'est: je vous confie quelqu'un. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Récompenser* can be followed by the prepositions *par* and *de*.

The former is either introducing the reward or the person granting it:

> *Il a été récompensé par la mention très-bien.*
>
> *Il a été récompensé par son professeur.*

The latter is either introducing the reward (rarer, more literary) or the reason why it is granted:

> *Il a été récompensé d'une médaille d'or.*
>
> *Il a été récompensé de ses efforts.*

In the following sentence:

> *Quand on avait mérité l'attention du maître, on était récompensé **par** la confiance qu'il vous faisait **d**'un malade pour un entretien particulier.*

both *par* and *de* are introducing a reward and the author used different prepositions to avoid a *repetition*. The sentence means the master granted his trust to the distinguished student as a reward, and this trust materialized by allowing him to have a private interview with a patient.

Comment: Ça y est, j'ai pigée. Confiance ici n'est pas avoir confiance en quelqu'un. C'est confiance dans le sens de remettre quelqu'un aux mains de quelqu'un d'autre. Voilà ce qui posait le problème ici pour un anglophone, en tout cas, à première vue.

Comment: @Lambie C'est intéressant comme interprétation mais existe-t-il des exemples attestés où « confiance » signifie « confier quelque chose/quelqu'un » ? Le TLFi ne connais pas cette acception.

Comment: Peut-être bien mais n'empêche qu'il y a une sorte de téléscopage dans la phrase, n'est-ce pas? "La répitition" qui est évité serait quelque chose comme: on était récompensé par la confiance qu'il vous faisait en vous confiant un malade pour un entretien particulier. Pour moi, confiance joue sur deux bords, pour ainsi dire.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was wondering about. I tried looking for the "remettre quelqu'un aux mains de quelqu'un d'autre" interpretation here, http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/confiance, but didn't see it.